# Retrieve the content of series data [] in Highcharts, after rendering the chart?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to add in the click event, a line of code that when I click on the chart, grab the content of the data [] in its series, to save it in a variable for future use.

Which one is the syntax to do so? this.chart.series didn't work.

I am planning to pass this to another chart, as data:

This is what I have so far; tried with get() also but I still get undefined errors

```
chart: {
    renderTo: 'chart',
    events: {
        click:function(event){
            extracteddata=this.chart.get('mainseries');
        }        
    },
}
```

When I print out in console; the only thing that I get is "this"; which return me the whole chart object including everything inside.

Tried so far with

```
this.series.option.data
this.data
this.series
```

And neither return the content of the array. I have printed out "this" and I can clearly see the series.data array which is correctly populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.series` is an array of series objects, so assuming you want the first series, use:

```
events: {
    click: function (event) {
        var someData = this.series[0].data;
    }
}
```

`someData` here is an array of point objects.  If you want just numbers use

```
this.series[0].yData
```

and/or

```
this.series[0].xData
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, finally I get something in the variables (using this.series[0].data). Now how can I pass this array of point objects to a chart? I need to pass the data contained in these series to another chart. Do I have to iterate each element manually, extract them and make a new array to feed to the other chart?

Comment: In case when you have two arrays of points, you need to merge them into one (array of arrays) and use in highcharts series.data object. Second solution is using only yAdata in series.data. All is up to you.